# Autolayout within Manual Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

Can I add autolayout views inside parent views that are using `frame, bounds, autoresizingMask` to position itself?

Usually on the internet you see the other way around, but I'm not able to achieve this case.

Edit:
I've added some code for you guys. Just create a new Xcode project with "Single View Application" and paste the following code on the ViewController.swift created for us.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let custom = CustomManualLayoutSubviews()
        let subview = UIView()
        let childView = UIView()

        custom.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        subview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        custom.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(custom)
        custom.addSubview(subview)
        subview.addSubview(childView)

        pin(child: custom, parent: view)
        pin(child: childView, parent: subview)
    }

    private func pin(child: UIView, parent: UIView) {
        parent.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view" : child]))
        parent.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[view]-10-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view" : child]))
    }
}


class CustomManualLayoutSubviews : UIView
{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        for subview in subviews {
            subview.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10)
            print("subview frame: \(subview)")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code, subview is using Manual Layout while custom and childView are using Autolayout. But the result is that the childView that uses autolayout is not displayed on the screen and when I inspect it I see it has a 0 width, 0 height.

That's what I get, there is no blue area at all.
[image]

Comment: Do you want to do by code?

Comment: Of course! It's impossible to be done by IB.

Comment: Currently you can make lots of conditional statements in IB.

Comment: Without adding autolayout constraint you can done by bounds see this tutorial http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2015112&seqNum=3

Comment: Commenting `subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` will solve your problem. The line of code prevents `CustomManualLayoutSubviews.layoutSubviews()` from taking effect.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you have to be very careful and are fairly limited.

Technically, if any view in a window is using auto layout, everything in the window uses auto layout. It's just that constraints are generated automatically from the `frame` and `autoresizingMask` for views whose `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is left on.

So, you have to make sure your constraints don't interfere with those automatically-generated constraints. You can "hang" stuff loosely off of the views using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, but your constraints must not "push" or "pull" on those views. The views using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` must have complete freedom of movement and sizing.

For example, you could use constraints to position a button a short distance in from the leading edge of the container view, but if you also constrain to the trailing edge, you had better make the content-hugging and compression-resistance priorities very low so that they don't try to change the width of the container. Even so, you may end up with conflicts. In auto layout, the width of views is not allowed to go negative. If the container is set to have zero width and the button has non-zero distance to the edges, then that will be a conflict. So, the constraint to the trailing edge should also have a low priority so that it can be broken if necessary. (Or you could do that for the leading edge.)

You say you're not able to achieve using auto layout within a view using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. You'll need to explain what you tried and what happened when you tried if you want further help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added some code to explain the issue in more details.

Comment: Any views whose frame, bounds, or position you set should have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to true and should not have constraints set that determine its position. Also, if you set those properties in an override of `layoutSubviews()`, you should call through to super *again* after you modify them. So, in your case, don't call `subview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` and add a second call to `super.layoutSubviews()` at the end of `layoutSubviews()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you can fix the above code and give me a fixed one, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: Also see http://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-auto-layout/ It says "You should also set translates​Autoresizing​Mask​Into​Constraints = NO on the view since you will position and size it manually, anyway"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As soon as 1 view has auto layout enabled, the entire window enables auto layout, translating frames into top, left, width and height constraints (respecting autoresizing mask)

So even though you might think you are manipulating frame or bounds or center properties, it'll be translated into auto layout behind the scenes, making it 100% compatible with you auto layout-enabled views.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added some code to explain the issue in more details.

Answer (score 0):

This links may helpful:

Auto layout programmatically

http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/

Programatically adding the views :

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2015112&seqNum=3

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added some code to explain the issue in more details.